# Getting cart Items that have reached to checkout

Tags: magento2

I need to fetch the

products of a customer that have reached to checkout + the products that customer has placed ordered for.

The collection should not include the items that are in the cart but the customer has not visited the checkout page , so in short

$products = previously ordered product + products that the customer has viewed on checkout page

Comment: When and where you need this product list?

Comment: @amit bera In a custom .phtml template

Comment: which page?Checkout page or other pages?

Comment: at the homepage which is loading the phtml file from custom module